# Why there is restriction to cite mantras or vedas?

Tags: vedas, mantras

In hinduism, there is a restriction to cite/ read mantras or vedas to the non-brahmins. It is regarded as sin if the non-brahmins read the contents in vedas or cites mantras. 
For example, we can cite gayatri mantra(Since we are brahmin). It is regarded as the most powerful mantra. But we are trained not to read/cite the mantra infront of any non-brahmin people.

Why is it like so in hinduism?

Comment: This restriction is due to the caste system. It is not relevant today. I have heard Americans reciting the gayatri.

Comment: @PradipGangopadhyay Just because they do, does not make it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This restriction, a by-product of the caste system is due to one interpretation of Hindu scripture. There are other interpretations that do not impose any restriction.

For example, in Mahabharata Santi Parva Section CCCXIX, Rishi Yajnavalkya is quoted as as saying,

> '.. All orders of men are Brahmanas. All are sprung from Brahma. All
> men utter Brahma. Aided by an understanding that is derived from and
> directed to Brahma.
>
> I inculcated this science teaching of Prakriti and
> Purusha. Indeed this whole universe is Brahma. From the mouth of
> Brahma sprung the Brahmanas; from his arms, sprung the Kshatriyas;
> from his navel, the Vaisysa; and from his feet, the Sudras. All the
> orders, (having sprung in this way) should not be regarded as
> pilfering from one another.
>
> Impelled by ignorance, all men meet with
> death and attain, O King, to birth that is the cause of acts. Divested
> of knowledge, all orders of men, dragged in terrible ignorance, fall
> into varied orders of being due to the principles that flow from
> Prakriti. For this reason, all should, by every means, seek to acquire
> knowledge.
>
> I have told thee that every person is entitled to strive
> for its acquisition. One that is possessed of knowledge is a Brahmana.
> Others, (viz., Kshatriyas, and Vaishyas and Sudras) are possessed of
> knowledge. Hence this science of emancipation is always open to them
> all.'

Comment: This is incorrect. There is something called adhikAra for mantra and vEda pArAyana. For e.g., women, even if born into brahmin families, cannot utter mantras or recite veda. Similarly there is "adhikAra nirNaya" for all people. In the taatvic sense, anyone can aspire to and attain brahmatvam or self-realization but mantra/veda practices are governed by adhikAra.

Comment: @moonstar2001 Harita Smriti says women *can* technically become a Brahmavadini if they don't want to be a housewife.

Comment: @Ikshvaku one cannot apply pre-historic sutras/allowances to kaliyuga.